# Is it possible to run a .do / Stata file as part of an R script?

Tags: r, stata

Currently, I am working on a project which builds upon existing code from a colleague. Their script was written in Stata, and thus is a .do file. However, the rest of the code in the project was developed using R. Is there a way to run the .do file at the beginning of the R script, in a similar way to the `source()` function? Further, will there be any additional difficulties in running the .do file in an Rmd, rather than just an R file?

I found one package, RStata, that seems promising, but I would like to compare any other options before going forward with this package.

Comment: Certainly nothing similar to `source`, it will be fundamentally different, since `source`’d code runs in the context of the current R session: it can manipulate the objects in your session, and vice versa. A solution that runs STATA code won’t be at all like this.

Comment: If you can run the .do file via a system command you might have a look at the `system` function to do this in r and then read the output of the stata script into r.